# Error: Cannot find module 'web3' when trying to use web3.js from Node

Tags: node.js, web3js

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032
> throw err;
> ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'web3'

I am getting this error when I am entering command node filename.js in terminal of Visual Studio Code.

and when I run (Ctrl+f5) then Google Chrome opens blank.

Comment: In your root folder, run `npm i web3`.

Comment: i have already installed web3 still its showing error..

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed web3.js? 
You can install it by using

```
npm install web3
```

if you have done it then please provide the code so i can check it.

Comment: Yes i have already installed web3. Here is my code.

Comment: const web3 = require('web3');
web3js = new web3(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/key"));
var contractABI = "ABI";
var contractAddress = "address";

var contract = new web3js.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);

contract.methods.ValidateDataInExcel('121', 'ok', 'fine').call()
    .then(function (result) { 
        console.log(result) 
    });

Comment: AAre you using any framework like express for rendering or you are rendering from client side. I also have the same error while i started working on web3. This is because web3 is not work on client side rendering we have to render our page from server side.

Comment: Please provide me the link to your github account or edit your question. I cannot understand the code in the comment section.

Comment: Thanks for info.. i am using visual studio code and it is working  now when i reinstalled web3.